# screen remains black after screen lock

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-10.10, hp-elitebook

My new installation of Ubuntu 10.10 by default locks the screen after doing nothing for 5 minutes. This is just what I want, but after that I am not able to unlock it again. The screen remains black when I move or click the mouse or even if I push a button on the keyboard.

I still found a workaround:

- press Ctrl+Alt+F8
- wait some seconds (the annoying part)
- press Ctrl+Alt+F7

Any idea what's wrong?

Hardware details:

- HP EliteBook 8440p
- Graphic card: NVIDIA NVS 3100M
- Driver: nvidia-current 260.19.06

Comment: Same problem. http://www.google.si/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEAQFjAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbugs.launchpad.net%2Fubuntu%2F%2Bsource%2Fxorg%2F%2Bbug%2F826397&rct=j&q=ubuntu%20black%20screen%20lock&ei=jRBYToWvIIjLswbYjN2aCw&usg=AFQjCNFk7NreuJX-cp-SKQO3aDzGeXK2zA&cad=rja

Comment: on 11.10 I also have the same problem, Ctrl Alt F1 and then Ctrl Alt F7 again also solves this for me, after a very annoying wait of about a minute. any good ideas?